# how to insert the data to dataframe using dictionary, if key is exist in column then set values

Tags: python, pandas

I make dataframe like follwing

```
column_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df = df.Dataframe(columns = column_list)
```

I want to add data by using dictionary list

and i want add values if dictionary key in colums

follwing is example

```
temp_list = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2}, {'B': 2, 'C': 4}]

A   | B | C
-----------
1   | 2 | NaN
NaN | 2 | 4
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way from `combine_first`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(temp_list).combine_first(df) #add reindex as protection pd.DataFrame(temp_list).combine_first(df).reindex(columns=column_list)

df
Out[153]: 
     A  B    C
0  1.0  2  NaN
1  NaN  2  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but directly passing the list of dicts works as well

```
pd.DataFrame([{'A': 1, 'B': 2}, {'B': 2, 'C': 4}]) # pd.DataFrame(temp_list)
```

Output

```
A   B   C
1.0 2   NaN
NaN 2   4.0
```